# How to get actual HTML elements in Chrome extension, not original source code

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension,

In Chrome's Inspect Elements panel, at the bottom will show all elements of the HTML page.

How can I get all those elements in JavaScript?

The page's original source code not include all of the elements.

How can I get all elements shown in Inspect Elements in my Chrome extension?

See these pictures: [this one is the elements I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyCDI.png), and [this one is the original source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bC54.png).

Comment: can you please provide an example of an element?

Comment: `get all the elements` - get where? what do you mean by "get"? `source code not include all elements` - which source code?

Comment: umm.... question doesn't make much sense, but to get an array of all HTML elements in the current page, you can call document.querySelectorAll('*');

Comment: the elements, in chrome press F12, and the content in the elements tab.      And the source code, in the web page press mouse right button ,choose show source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any elements that you see in the JavaScript inspector, but not in the HTML source code, are either (a) automatically added by the browser to normalize the any missing elements (i.e. no `<body>` tag) or correcting invalid structure (i.e. unclosed `<p>` tag) to make the document valid, or (b) added by JavaScript.

**Any technique you use to inspect the document from your Chrome extension will automatically see the document as you see it in the document inspector.** You don't need to do anything specific. All of the elements that have been created by the browser or by JavaScript will be there. For example, you could use `document.querySelectorAll('*')` to get an array-like object containing all of them, or `document.body.outerHTML` to get the HTML code.

The harder task would actually be if you wanted to get the original, uncorrected source code.

Answer (score 1):

I just use the JavaScript `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]` and I get all I want.

I don't know why I didn't get the right result yesterday.